# Define function of n variables and integrate

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

Im looking at n particles and functions of their coordinates which I want to integrate over:

```
{r1, r2,..., rn} = Table[Symbol["r" <> ToString@i], {i, n}] =: LoC[n_]
```

then I want to define functions e.g.

```
f[x_] := x

g[L_] := Sum[f[i], {i, L}]
```

where later I plug in L = LoC[n].

Then I define intervals for integration:

```
IB[i_] := {Symbol["r" <> ToString@i], x, R} = {r1, x, R}

IIB[n_] := Array[IB, n] = {{r1, x, R},...., {rn, x, R}}
```

but the integration doesnt work:

```
NIntegrate[g[LoCC[3]], Row[IIB[3], ","]].
```

With errors like "NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {r1,1,100}, {r2,1,100}, {r3,1,100}."

What am I doing wrong? I guess the arguments or the integration limits arent defined properly.

n=2 (x=1, R=100):

```
LoC[2]
IB[2]
IIB[2]

Out[10]= {r1, r2}

Out[11]= {r2, 1, 100}

Out[12]= {{r1, 1, 100}, {r2, 1, 100}}

In[32]:= g[LoC[2]]

Out[32]= r1 + r2
```

The row command removes one pair of brackets {} because Integrate wants the integration limits like

{r1, 1, 100}, {r2, 1, 100}

```
In[33]:= Row[IIB[2], ","]

Out[33]= {r1, 1, 100}, {r2, 1, 100}
```

but then

```
In[34]:= NIntegrate[g[LoC[2]], Row[IIB[2], ","]]

During evaluation of In[34]:= NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration 
variable or limit(s) in {r1,1,100},{r2,1,100}.

Out[34]= NIntegrate[g[LoC[2]], Row[IIB[2], ","]]
```

Comment: You can't integrate across limits in a `Row` - that's for presentation. Remove the `Row`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integration limits can't be `Row` and there were some syntax issues I cleaned up. Hopefully the comments `(* ... *)` below explain everything. You can change the $x,R,n$ in the `With` to different values if needed:

```
(* Function to create the symbols r[1],r[2],...,r[n] *)
LoC[n_] := Array[r,n]

(* Functions to integrate *)
f[x_] := x
g[l_] := Sum[f[i], {i, l}]

(* Function to generate an interval for integration *)
iv[variable_, x_, R_] := {variable, x, R}

(* Given x,R,n - integrate g[LoC[n]]. *)
With[{x = 1, R = 100, n = 3},
 NIntegrate[g[LoC[n]],
  (* generate intervals and splice into arguments here with Sequence *)
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ (iv[#, x, R] & /@ LoC[n])]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Good cleanup. While you are at it, I would suggest changing the `Symbol`+`ToString` stuff to regular indexed variables, like `r[1], r[2],...`. Then `LoC` is simply `Array[r, n]` or `r /@ Range[n]`.

Comment: Done. Much cleaner looking.

Comment: Thaanks! No way I wouldve figured that out. :)